# Data Migration from Dynamo Db to AWS RDS Mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS dynamo db to store data. Now i want to export it into mysql.

i just want a way so that, so that i can export data from dynamo db to mysql on regular basis.
Mysql will be work as backup db.

**what will be the best approached!**

Comment: This would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120041/how-to-export-data-from-amazon-dynamodb-into-mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

Write code in java using scan functionality of Dynamo DB and export the data out into file, you can later use RDS specific SQL Load utility. You  have to use lastkey feature of DynamoDB to continue scan for next call and continue the scan to avoid outofmemory error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my simple node.js script [dynamo-archive](https://github.com/yegor256/dynamo-archive), which exports to JSON format. Then you can parse it and import to MySQL.